# Парсер на Python - Подгрузка записей AJAX кнопкой через POST запрос

Tags: python, xpath, requests

Вопрос в следующем. Сайт [вот он](https://www.biz-cen.ru) имеет кнопку "загрузить ещё".
Судя по XHR панели её вызов - POST запрос к адресу`https://www.biz-cen.ru/load/`

На питоне мой запрос выглядит вот так

```
r = requests.post('https://www.biz-cen.ru/load/', data={"bcs_in_view":["85",
"254",
"29",
"660"]})
```

Судя по результату, которого нет, я допустил ошибку. Скрипт до сих пор видит то же число запрашиваемых постов, сколько и до запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, вы мало данных отправляете в форме. Попробуйте так:

```
form_data = {
    'was_bc_loaded': 0,
    'search_params':{
        "metro":{"lines":{}},
        "was_ra":",",
        "limit":20,
        "to_ra":0,
        "tolim":20,
        "bc_in_fav":[],
        "office_in_fav":[],
        "bcs_in_view_start":[],
        "num_in":3,
        "typeof_search":9,
        "show_fav":0,
        "bcs_in_view":["272", ...]
    }
}
```

С каждым новым запросом `limit` увеличивается на 21, то есть следующий будет 41, потом 62, 83 и т.д. Перед каждым запросом меняете значение `limit` и отправляете:

```
r = requests.post('https://www.biz-cen.ru/load/', json=form_data)
```